# Unix commands in C code

Tags: c, unix

I need to implement ps -auxj, grep "user id", and wc. I already have word count, but I'm not sure how to do the others while they have parameters. This is what I have so far.

```
int main() {
int pfd[2];
int pid;

if (pipe(pfd) == -1) {
    perror("pipe failed");
    exit(-1);
}
if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("fork failed");
    exit(-2);
}
if (pid == 0) {
    close(pfd[1]);
    dup2(pfd[0], 0);
    close(pfd[0]);
    execlp("wc", "wc", (char *) 0);
    perror("wc failed");
    exit(-3);
} 
else {
    close(pfd[0]);
    dup2(pfd[1], 1);
    close(pfd[1]);
    execlp("ls", "ls", (char *) 0);
    perror("ls failed");
    exit(-4);
}
exit(0);
```

}

Any help in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Have you looked at `man 3 exec` yet?  It should explain everything you need to know about argument passing using the exec* functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[exec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/exec.html)  gives details about how to pass arguments to the exec family of functions.
e.g.

```
execl("ls", "ls", "-l",(char *) 0);
```

you can choose from there whatever suits you.